# Sorento Speed Boost on Brake

Tags: brakes, kia

So I've been driving automatic vehicles for a while now. Now I want to learn manual driving so I bought a Kia Sorento 2005. For the most part Im doing ok, my main problem now is that I'm still getting used to the different ways of breaking without stalling the engine...

One thing that keeps happening and (as a software developer) not sure if its a bug or a feature: **While in third gear if I hit the brake the car will noticeable gain a 'speed boost'**, this pushes me to clutch-brake to stop at, for example, the junction (then go back to first gear and start from there).

A bit of the [Sorento (2005) users manual](https://www.kia.ca/content/ownership/ownersmanual/2005_sorento_Owners_Manual_EN.pdf) reads:

[image]

I'm not sure what to make of this but, is this related in any way? or: is this something normal and I'm just taking the wrong approach towards taking a corner and I shouldn't be in third gear anyway?

Comment: Does the RPM increase when you hit the brake?  Can this be reproduced in neutral?  Could be the brake booster causing a vacuum leak.

Comment: @rpmerf I'll need to check the RPMs... It cannot be reproduced in neutral, I've only ever tried as high as third gear, does not happen in second or first gear.

Comment: How high are the RPM when this happens?  Something that takes a little getting used to driving a clutch.  If you RPM is below about 1500, the engine is trying to maintain RPM.  In an automatic, the torque converter disengages.  In a manual, the clutch still has the engine coupled to the engine.  It may not accelerate, but feel like it does because the car isn't slowing as fast.  If the RPM drops low enough, it will open the idle valve to keep the RPM up.  Sometimes it holds a little higher RPM (1500 or so) for a couple seconds to make downshifting easier.

Answer (score 1):

No car should accelerate when you step on the brakes.  This is NOT a feature.

The only interaction the brakes have with your engine is via vacuum.  If there was some sort of damage to the brake booster (say, a massive vacuum leak) your engine would start sucking air that it wasnt expecting to suck.  This would make it run rough, but i dont see how it would make it accelerate.

That it happens only in 3rd gear suggests some sort of transmission issue, but i cant imagine what that would possibly be to make the car accelerate when you are trying to make it stop.  Especially given that the brakes and transmission are not connected.  At all.

I would guess damage to the pedal assemblies.  But again, given that it only happens in third that makes little sense.